# Basic PHP CMS help needed. If the page isn't available, it should show a error page instead

Tags: php, arrays, content-management-system

Okay, so I have this 10+ year old PHP code I cobbled together to make a basic PHP driven site. It works and I'm using it in production now. But I have a problem that I can't figure out the solution to!

Here is my index.php code, this is probably all that is relevant.

```
<?php
require("./config.php");
$okfiles = array("main","page1","some-other-page","anotherexample");
if ($_GET["p"] AND @in_array( $_GET["p"] , $okfiles ) ) {
    $includeFile = $_GET["p"] .".php";
    if (@file_exists($includeFile)){
        include($includeFile);
    }
}
else {
    include("./main.php");
}
?>
```

So, user goes to `website.tld`, and index.php is served. What is shown on the index page is the content of main.php on the webserver. If they navigate to `website.tld/page1`, they then see the content of page1.php within the basic little templating system I have. That is what I want. Some Nginx re-write rules make it look nice and all is good there.

The **issue** I am having is if someone goes to `website.tld/a-page-that-doesnt-exist`, instead of seeing the web-server's default 404 page, instead, they just see the content of main.php as if they had went to the website's index instead of a page that should trigger an error. ***HOWEVER***, if they got to `website.tld/a-page-that-doesn-exist.php` (or any other page/request that has a file extension associated with it... They see the error page.

How can I make it that if the page being requested isn't defined in `$okfiles = array` that it then triggers a normal error page?

Comment: Change your `else` so that it displays an error page instead of `main.php`

Comment: If I do that, then index.php shows the 404 page instead of the content within main.php.

Comment: You should treat a missing `p` option differently from a value that isn't in `$okfiles`. Only go to the 404 page when the parameter is given and it's not OK.

Comment: That is what I would like to do. But I do not know how to do it. This is very old code that I saved a decade ago and I'm an old man now who is just trying to get back into websites.